# Can not enable ionCube extension

Tags: php-5.5, ioncube

I had download ionCube, 
copy `ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so` in 
folder `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/`  and add this line to php.ini file

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so
```

then I had run `sudo service apache2 restart` 
apache run but ionCube extension is not loaded.

Where I make wrong steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this url as solution for ionCube problem

```
https://www.howtoforge.com/install-ioncube-loader-for-all-php-modes-cli-cgi-fcgi-and-fpm-on-debian-wheezy
```